# PC not seeing all button presses from paired Fire TV remote

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control, peripherals

Fire TV remote is paired to PC running Win 7 and successfully sends button presets from some buttons, but not others. The directional, Enter, and Home buttons work, but none of the others do.

I used Autohotkey to see the button presses and map to keys that control XBMC.

Suggestions for troubleshooting to get all buttons working?